# MediaPlayer seekTo method is not accurate

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I want to seek to a specified position on mp3 file, my proplem is the MediaPlayer seek to about 31 seconds ahead, for example I want to seek to 136540 mSeconds which means 2 Minutes and 16 Seconds, the MediaPlayer seek instead to 1 Minutes and 45 Seconds

here is my code

```
 File[] ffile1 = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);
    String mp3FilePath =ffile1[0].getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "002.mp3";
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3FilePath);
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        SystemClock.sleep(200);
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(136540);
        SystemClock.sleep(200);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the mp3 file that I use https://download.quranicaudio.com/qdc/abdul_baset/mujawwad/2.mp3 
Please help, Thanks

Comment: try to set on prepare listener

Comment: @Style-7, The same problem :(

Comment: try to use another video, may be video file is corrupted

Comment: @Style-7 I tested another mp3 from the same site, It works good, but the file that has a problem works and seek good with windows media pleayer and VLC player, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to MP3s, depending on their encoding, `MediaPlayer` can't always parse them correctly, and so the seek function is essentially broken. It has to do with the variable bit rate not being properly encoded in the MP3 itself.

Instead of `MediaPlayer`, try using [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). It's a fairly simple drop-in replacement, which shouldn't require you to change too much code